# Using Font Awesome in Adobe Flex 3

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flex3, font-awesome, mxml

Is it possible to use Font Awesome icons in Adobe Flex 3 since it doesn't allow inline CSS style? If so, how to set the text of Button or Label to properly be shown as icon in Flex?

Currently, I have the following setup for Flex 3.6A and the button isn't showing the icon properly:

[image: File Structure]

Here is the simplify version of ...View.mxml placed in components package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
       currentState="default">
<mx:Style source="../assets/styles.css"/>
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="Hide"/>
    <mx:State name="default">
        <mx:AddChild>
            <mx:HBox>
                <mx:Button label="&#xf011;" styleName="complete" id="completeButton" fontFamily="FontAwesome"/>
                <mx:Button id="skipButton" />
                <mx:Button id="shareButton" />
                <mx:Button id="deleteButton" />
                <mx:Button id="progressButton" />
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
    <mx:State name="Expand"/>
</mx:states>    
</mx:Canvas>
```

Here is the content of styles.css:

```
@font-face {
    fontFamily:             FontAwesome;
    embed-as-cff:           true;
    src:                    url("font-awesome-4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    fontStyle:              normal;
}
@font-face {
    fontFamily:             FontAwesomeNonCff;
    embed-as-cff:           false;
    src:                    url("font-awesome-4.7.0/fonts/FontAwesome.otf");
    fontStyle:              normal;
}

.complete {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: red;
}
```

Here is what the button looks like:
[image: Complete Button]

Comment: I think you'll have to download the TTF and then maybe also need to embed it before you're able to use it. Have you tried that?

Comment: I am rather new to Flex, and I am not quite sure to embed it and use it properly.

Comment: Ok, I gave it a try and it seems to work. Please see my answer below and please let me know if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for adding in your code and formatting it. Upvoted. I am still not able to reproduce your problem. I am trying with `mx:Button` now and I did get some warnings. Are you getting any warnings in your console? Can you please paste in a screenshot of your folder structure especially how your fonts and css are located in the project? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question with the folder structure. I don't think it is structuring issue as it will give me errors when I used a wrong indirect path. And no, I have no warning for this mxml. Everything is running fine especially when running the debug mode. I don't think you can reproduce the issue unless you tried running it as Flex 3. I know, for sure, it will work for Flex 4, which led me to the question of whether Font-Awesome is compatible or not for Flex 3. (Note that there is a warning for another unrelated mxml file under objects package.)

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue with Flex 3.6A. I believe I was able to fix it by adding a simple `fontWeight:normal;` attribute to your `.complete` class. Can you please give it a try? If it works, I will update my answer below so that you can mark it as selected.

Comment: Oh, wow. That was the solution?! I didn't expect that. Please do update your answer and I will mark it as solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yup, it's strange, but that's the only way it works. I have updated my answer below, please do upvote and mark as the selected answer. Glad to have helped :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just gave this a try and it seems to work. Please follow these steps to use font-awesome font in Flex.

First of all download the .ttf font from the font-awesome website. Next, import the .ttf file into your Flex application preferably inside a package. I created a package called as `assets/fonts`, but it's totally upto you where you keep it in your project.

Once done, create a style sheet, I called it `styles.css` in any package of your choice. I created it in a package named `assets/css`. Create your font-face style in the style sheet:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

@font-face 
{
    src:url("assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    fontFamily: fontawesome;
}

.buttons
{
    fontFamily:fontawesome;
    fontSize:20;
    color:#000000;
}
```

I also created a selector class named as `buttons` to be used on your buttons. Notice the path of the font file and make sure it matches your folder structure where it's kept. Also, notice that I am using the fontFamily as `fontawesome` in the `buttons` CSS selector.

Next, import your css into the flex project and use the style name in your buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Style source="assets/css/styles.css"/>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button width="100" height="40" top="50" left="50" label="&#xf2bb;" styleName="buttons"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Important thing to note here is the `label` property of the button. You have to use the **Unicode** value for the icon found next to the icon in the font-awesome [cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/).

And once you run your code you should be able to see the font appearing in the button. Attached screenshot below for your reference.

[image]

PS: I am using Flex 4.x, so you may have to make some code adjustments, but the basic concept should remain the same.

**UPDATE**: For Flex 3.6A, make sure that you are adding the attribute of `fontWeight:normal` to your CSS selector to make it work. It's strange, but without it, it does not seem to work. So CSS would be:

```
.buttons
{
    fontFamily:fontawesome;
    fontSize:20;
    fontWeight:normal;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I have a similar setup as yours before, and did attempt to alter mine more closely to yours, but it didn't work for Flex 3. CSS selector works fine as I was able to color the font, but the button label shows up as something like " ' " for "&#xf011". I don't know what I need to add or modify for it to work.

Comment: In that case please update your question by placing your code in it.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but I'm still getting the same error as OP: An unknown character :/
I'm using Flex 4.16 and fontawesome 4.7. 
Did you change something else on code? Or just the css and mxml file?
Thanks!